# Java code to flip an image, two dimensional array with IntStream?

Tags: java

I'm working on coding questions in Java to try and refresh my java brain cells. I came across this question and did not understand what the given answer is actually doing. I guess I never worked with java streams.

```java
  public int[][] flipImage(int[][] image) {
    return IntStream
             .range(0, image.length)
             .mapToObj(i -> image[image.length - 1 - i])
             .toArray(int[][]::new);
  }
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)? Which part specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I didn't read the docs but `range( 0..image.length)` seems one dimensional and the image array is two dimensional.  Does this actually "flip" anything?

Comment: @markspace It flips the rows top to bottom.

Comment: That's what I thought.  But the name of the method is "flipImage" and this doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: @shmosel I don't really understand what the mapToObj is doing, as well as the `.toArray(int[][]::new)`. The whole process here is somewhat confusing. Is it somewhat equivalent to the javascript `.map()` method?

Comment: Yes, it's very similar, except that's it's lazy evaluated. `int[][]::new` is equivalent to `len -> new int[len][]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the equivalent of this:

```
int[][] flipped = new int[image.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    flipped[i] = image[image.length - 1 - i];
}
```

Comment: So it's reversing the elements and putting them in the first column of the array? I guess the 2-d-ness of it is messing me up.